# Need help understanding something from the dubia around Traditionis Custodes

Tags: catholicism, liturgy, extraordinary-form-of-the-mass, traditionis-custodes

The last point that the Bishops got in response about ***Traditionis Custodes*** was:

> A parish priest or chaplain who is authorized to celebrate the traditional Mass but must also celebrate the ordinary form of the Mass during the week cannot then also celebrate the traditional Mass on the same day (binate).

https://www.ncregister.com/news/traditions-custodies-vatican-responses-to-11-dubia

My parish priest has three Weekend Masses a Novus Ordo vigil Mass in English, a Novus Ordo morning mass in English, followed by a TLM Mass, followed by a Novus Ordo Mass in Spanish.  Does this mean  that a priest can't celebrate two different liturgical forms of the Mass on the same day?

Comment: Think this sounds more and more like Pope Francis has an agenda here.

Answer (score 3):

**According to [*Traditionis Custodes*](https://www.vatican.va/content/francesco/en/motu_proprio/documents/20210716-motu-proprio-traditionis-custodes.html), is it now obligatory that a priest can not celebrate two different forms of the Mass on the same day?**

According to *Traditionis Custodes*, there is no clear wording that even comes close to the new rule expressed in the Vatican’s new guidelines through its response to the 11 ***dubia*** referred to. So why the additional new ruling?

The new dubia states the following as coming from the **Congregation for Divine Worship**:

> They were approved by Pope Francis in a private audience with Archbishop Roche on Nov. 18, and are dated Dec. 4, the 58th anniversary of the promulgation of the Second Vatican Council’s Constitution on the Sacred Liturgy, *Sacrosanctum Concilium*.
>
> In summary, Archbishop Roche has ruled the following:
>
> - A parish priest or chaplain who is authorized to celebrate the traditional Mass but must also celebrate the ordinary form of the Mass during the week cannot then also celebrate the traditional Mass on the same day (binate).
>
> [Vatican’s New Guidelines Further Restrict Traditional Rites](https://www.ncregister.com/news/traditions-custodies-vatican-responses-to-11-dubia)

According to the **Congregation for Divine Worship**,  “a priest can't celebrate two different forms of the Mass on the same day!”

However, ***Traditionis  Custodes*** does not state that at all. (Not even closely!) So what gives?

Got the feeling that some that are working within the Vatican simply want the Rite of Pope Pius V gone. The old mass was never abrogated, so Rome can not suppress a valid form of worship. If not treated correctly, with dignity and respect there is going to be a serious reaction on the subject of worship within the Church and I fear Pope Francis will be responsible in a large part for it. Division is brewing and who knows what will happen.

The Vatican says that the ***dubia*** are a result of the most recurrent questions it has received about Pope Francis’ recent *motu proprio* ***Traditionis Custodes***.

It is time for Pope Francis and the Vatican to have transparency and name the bishops that asked this particular question ***dubium*** (if any)!

Comment: Also @PeterTurner Just saw this [Feb 2022 decree](https://fssp.com/decree/) given to FSSP, after a personal visit asking for clarification from Pope Francis a week earlier, giving all FSSP priests permission to use 1962 forms.  Looks like a good sign?